# C++ detection idiom without void_t

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

How I can implement C++ [detection idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) without using `void_t`? In other words, can I implement C++17 `std::is_detected` etc using only C++03-features?

**UPD** Detection idiom requires C++11 by definition. In my question I just meant that I want to implement `is_detected` somehow without `void_t`. My problem is in it: unused parameters in alias templates were not guaranteed to ensure SFINAE and could be ignored, ans VS 2013 has this defect; another tries (like on cppreference) leads to compiler crash (yep, `cl` is *the greatest* compiler in the world).

**UPD2** I suppose that VS 2013 can break any C++ metaprogramming techniques (and programmer's brains too).

Comment: Why can't you implement `void_t` in C++03?

Comment: @Justin because c++03 doesn't have variadic template arguments.

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, I know. You can't implement a variadic `void_t`, but you could easily make a non-variadic one. And if C++-03 doesn't have variadic templates, you can't quite create a variadic `is_detected`, but you could, for example, do it for a single argument only

Comment: One thing to note: instead of `void_t`, you can do `decltype((void)(...))`; basically cast the expression to void.

Comment: @Justin but `decltype` is C++11...

Answer (score 4):

Back in the <strike>good</strike> old days, this is how we do it

```
template<typename T>
T declval();

template<typename T>
struct can_foo
{
    typedef char yes;
    struct no {char c[2];};

    template<typename U>
    static yes check(int (*)[sizeof(declval<U>().foo(), 1)]);
    template<typename>
    static no check(...);

    enum {value = sizeof(check<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes)};
};

struct fooer
{
    void foo() {}  
};
struct barer
{
    void bar() {}  
};

#include<cassert>

int main()
{
    assert(can_foo<fooer>::value);
    assert(!can_foo<barer>::value);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70c7ec590affc28c)

The trick is to abuse `sizeof` as much as possible.

Note that the `declval` is different from `std::declval`.

Comment: You wrote: "Note that the declval is different from std::declval."
I prefer to define static members like `template <typename U> static U make();` for this purposes

Comment: It seems that this code doesn't work on VS 2013 (both `value`s are true) :(((

Comment: @MichaelGaluza I opted for a free function to emulate similarity with current methods. That VS2013 rejects this is... spectacular.

Comment: c'est la vie)))

Comment: Is it important that `declval` returns by value or can you use `std::declval` too?

Comment: @Pezo There isn't `std::declval` in C++03, but otherwise, yes

Answer (score 3):

Since the question was modified and C++ 11 is allowed, I post almost a copy-paste from cppreference, no credit taken.

```
namespace detail {
struct nonesuch {
  nonesuch() = delete;
  ~nonesuch() = delete;
  nonesuch(nonesuch const&) = delete;
  void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
};

template <class Default, class AlwaysVoid, template <class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct detector {
  using value_t = std::false_type;
  using type = Default;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct my_make_void {
  typedef void type;
};

template <typename... Ts>
using my_void_t = typename my_make_void<Ts...>::type;

template <class Default, template <class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct detector<Default, my_void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> {
  using value_t = std::true_type;
  using type = Op<Args...>;
};

} // namespace detail

template <template <class...> class Op, class... Args>
using is_detected =
  typename detail::detector<detail::nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t;

template <class T>
using copy_assign_t = decltype(std::declval<T&>() = std::declval<const T&>());

struct Meow {};
struct Purr {
  void operator=(const Purr&) = delete;
};

int main() {
  cerr << is_detected<copy_assign_t, Meow>::value << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is one trouble — VS 2013 doesn't support it in any way (I've tried to use this approach from cppreference).